# $.ajax() get request success function is not being called with MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

I suspect it's because I'm not returning JSON that can be parsed. Here is a sample:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/json";
Response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new {foo="bar"}));
```

Chrome tells me the following..."Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : "

This approach yields the same response:

```
return Json(new {foo="bar"}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

What am I doing wrong? Also, this is a cross domain request.

```
$.ajax({
        url: myURL,
        type: 'GET',
        async: true,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
```

EDIT: Here is the JSON C# spits out:

```
{"foo":"bar"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that it's because dataType expected by jQuery is setup to jsonp, but you don't return [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP). Change it to json or even use:

```
$.get(myUrl, { cache: false }).done(function (data) {
    alert(data);
});
```